# When do you unlock each of Beep-o's abilities?

Tags: mario-plus-rabbids-kingdom-battle

When exploring an area, you often come across some environmental pieces you can't quite interact with. What do you unlock after each area and what do the abilities do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beep-o gets 4 abilities:

- Push - unlocked after completing world 1
- Carry - unlocked after completing world 2
- Break - unlocked after completing world 3
- Dig - unlocked after completing world 4

**Push** is used to solve any puzzle where you would normally be moving blocks around on the ground. Most of the time your aim is to move a specific block onto a switch to depress it and open a door.

**Carry** is used to move statues onto pedestals. Wherever you see a block that is unmovable and looks like the other shape/color blocks, you can very likely find a statue nearby to pick up and place on the pedestal.

**Break** is used to break fragile blocks, paving the way to new areas or sometimes revealing chests underneath them. Any time you see breakable blocks, make sure you break all of them - you never know where you'll find a chest.

**Dig** is used to dig up piles of dirt, normally to be used in conjunction with the Push ability.

Normally you'll see a *lot* of places to use these abilities in the world they're unlocked in. If you're like me and want to figure out how to do something before continuing on, know that you have a hard limit and must progress first and come back later or you'll be spending a lot of time staring at the "I don't know how to do that" bubble.